Hierarchical clustering of a distance matrix with element weights
I am computing a hierarchical clustering of some geospatial data. I need to add in an element weighting to the approach.
My current approach is:
I compute temporal cross-correlations between my N locations and then converting the resulting NxN correlation matrix, C, into a distance matrix D:
D=sqrt(1-C) [following this discussion]
Then I cluster D into K clusters using scipy, minimising the maximum distance between points in a cluster:
D_condensed= np.concatenate([row[i+1:] for i, row in enumerate(D)])
linkage = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(D_condensed, method='complete')
cluster_labels = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster(linkage, K, 'maxclust')

However, as my N data points represent a MxL latitude-longitude grid, the density of points is much higher near the pole than at the equator. The result is the algorithm favours small polar clusters and larger equatorial clusters. Therefore I would like to add a weighting equal to the area represented by each gridpoint, so that the clustering algorithm preferentially favours equatorial gridpoints.
This would be represented by a length N array of weights W.
An example of the problem when using the unweighted case:


Would it be correct to understand your problem as resulting from an effective oversampling of polar regions due to the use of lat-lon to generate the grid?  Regardless, it would help to explain what you hope this clustering will accomplish, because that would suggest possible alternatives or corrections you can apply.

It sounds like this is an issue of geospatial projection. You’ll need to either transform your lat/lon into Cartesian coordinates, or modify your distance function to account for the areal distortion.
See this SO thread, or (better yet) the GIS stack exchange for an example of transforming coordinates to Cartesian. The exact transformation you need will depend on the specific projection of your data, and how the coordinates are represented.

The GIS site has (literally) thousands of threads about this topic, going far beyond the SO thread you reference, so I would suggest it would serve as a better resource for this subject.//Several re-readings of the original post suggest to me the problem is not directly related to the projection, but rather arises from how the earth's surface was partitioned into grid cells.  A reprojection would help only if the raw data--before computing the correlation matrix $C$--could be adequately resampled, which brings about many more problems to solve... .

That could certainly be the case; my assumption here was that OP's original data was point-referenced on a lat/lon coordinate system based on the phrase 'density of points', but if the data is areal and sampled on a pre-defined grid then that does raise a whole bevy of other issues.

Yes, I'm afraid the underlying data is area averaged rainfall, output from a numerical model in lat-lon format directly. Thus I am trying to work out how to weight my distance matrix to account for the polar oversampling, as I can't easily remap the underlying data.

I’d start by re-projecting to rectangular coordinates and see if that does it; the specific projection may be hiding somewhere in the metadata if you’re working with a format like GRIB or NetCDF, or it could be evident from the specific model (e.g. lambert conical projections seem to be popular with downscaled models)
